# Error: Token must be defined! when testing with Angular 2 RC5

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-testing

Back in June 2016, I wrote an article on how to test Angular 2 applications. I used [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) as a starting point.

https://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/testing_angular_2_0_rc1

I decided to rewrite this tutorial using Angular CLI (from its master branch), which uses Angular 2 RC5. I'm seeing a strange error from one of my tests.

```
Error: Token must be defined!
    at new BaseException (/Users/mraible/ng2-demo/src/test.ts:1940:23 <- webpack:///Users/mraible/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/src/facade/exceptions.js:27:0)
    at new ReflectiveKey (/Users/mraible/ng2-demo/src/test.ts:27600:19 <- webpack:///Users/mraible/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_key.js:36:0)
    at KeyRegistry.get (/Users/mraible/ng2-demo/src/test.ts:27641:22 <- webpack:///Users/mraible/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_key.js:77:0)
    at Function.ReflectiveKey.get (/Users/mraible/ng2-demo/src/test.ts:27615:35 <- webpack:///Users/mraible/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_key.js:51:0)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (/Users/mraible/ng2-demo/src/test.ts:58418:62 <- webpack:///Users/mraible/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector.js:586:0)
    at NgModuleInjector.get (/Users/mraible/ng2-demo/src/test.ts:40942:52 <- webpack:///Users/mraible/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/src/linker/ng_module_factory.js:98:0)
    at TestBed.get (/Users/mraible/ng2-demo/src/test.ts:11910:47 <- webpack:///Users/mraible/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.js:269:0)
    at /Users/mraible/ng2-demo/src/test.ts:11916:61 <- webpack:///Users/mraible/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.js:275:46
    at Array.map (native)
    at TestBed.execute (/Users/mraible/ng2-demo/src/test.ts:11916:29 <- webpack:///Users/mraible/ng2-demo/~/@angular/core/testing/test_bed.js:275:0)
```

Here's my test:

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import { TestComponentBuilder } from '@angular/compiler/testing';

import { MockActivatedRoute } from '../shared/search/mocks/routes';
import { MockSearchService } from '../shared/search/mocks/search.service';

import { EditComponent } from './edit.component';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { inject } from "@angular/core/testing/test_bed";

describe('Component: Edit', () => {
  var mockSearchService:MockSearchService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockSearchService = new MockSearchService();

    return [
      mockSearchService.getProviders(),
      provide(ActivatedRoute, { useValue: new MockActivatedRoute({ 'id': '1' }) })
    ];
  });

  it('should fetch a single record', inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb:TestComponentBuilder) => {
    return tcb.createAsync(EditComponent).then((fixture) => {
      let person = {name: 'Emmanuel Sanders', address: {city: 'Denver'}};
      mockSearchService.setResponse(person);

      fixture.detectChanges();
      // verify service was called
      expect(mockSearchService.getByIdSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);

      // verify data was set on component when initialized
      let editComponent = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
      expect(editComponent.editAddress.city).toBe('Denver');

      // verify HTML renders as expected
      var compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      expect(compiled.querySelector('h3')).toBe('Emmanuel Sanders');
    });
  }));
});
```

I've posted this project to GitHub so you can reproduce this issue if you like: https://github.com/mraible/ng2-demo.

Comment: any luck finding a solution for this? I'm hitting the same issue while trying to unit test via `ng test` through the angular cli tooling.

Comment: This was caused by my import - I had to change it to `import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';`. You can see the whole test here: https://github.com/mraible/ng2-demo/blob/master/src/app/edit/edit.component.spec.ts

Answer (score 1):

Matt, I've copied in what I think are the relevant lines of [your working code](https://github.com/mraible/ng2-demo/blob/master/src/app/edit/edit.component.spec.ts) to help any one who may stumble across this question in the future.

You mentioned your fix was to import `TestBed` from `@angular/core/testing`, and I noticed you also followed the guidance of injecting mock services, in a manner that is reflected in the [angular testing documentation and guidelines](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#component-with-dependency) as well.

My fix was a little different; it was due to a misnaming of one of the services that I had provided in the `TestBed.configureTestingModule()` method.

**For example,** in your case, you instantiate a new `MockSearchService` and pass it into the `providers` array as `mockSearchService`, as such: `{provide: SearchService, useValue: mockSearchService}`.

In my case, I passed in the `MockSearchService` *type* (NOTE, the actual type, not an instance), as follows: `{provide: SearchService, useValue: MockSearchService}` (note the capitalization)...

...and then got an instance of the service as follows: `mockSearchService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MockSearchService);`.

However, in my case, I mis-spelled the value I passed in as `...injector.get(mockSearchService)` which was an invalid token to pass into the injector getter. So, I think this invalid token error is thrown by Karma, or one of the other tools involved in the test process as a catch all case for trying to access or pass in a token that is undefined. Moral of the story, it likely had to do with a misnaming of a variable somewhere. Your case is a little different, but I'm almost positive it was related somehow :]. Cheers!

## Your working code

```
import { MockSearchService } from '../shared/search/mocks/search.service';
// other imports ...

describe('Component: Edit', () => {
    let mockSearchService: MockSearchService;
    // other service declarations...

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockSearchService = new MockSearchService();
        // other service instances...

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            // declarations...

            providers: [
                {provide: SearchService, useValue: mockSearchService},

                // other providers...
            ],

            // imports...
        });
    });

    // Tests ...

});
```